# It seems /login is a reserved route - is that correct?

Tags: routes, login

When I hit /login in a browser, I am redirected to the home page (this is on a vanilla install without any entries or routes set up).

Is this a reserved route? 
Can I change that so I can use it for my own route? 
If it's reserved, what other routes are there that we should know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is set by the [`loginPath` config setting](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#loginPath) so yes, you can change it in your `craft/config/general.php` file.

There are a few other configurable URLs for templates and redirects, all of which are described on that page.